# When I have customized same acumatica screen in two customization package

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

When I have customized same acumatica screen in two customization package after publishing both customization package
only One is working  why its happening Please help.

Comment: It could be due to how events are written in your code or how you are overriding Acumatica methods.

Comment: You should include some basic example of code you are using. When you say only one is working... is this a UI change which is visible only from one customization or you are talking about runtime code based on some graph extension?

Comment: Yes it has UI changes in acumatica extended screen in two customization...both Cusomization we have extended Bill of material screen  and In both customization have changes at UI of Middile grid ....Only one customization UI changes reflected..